# Laravel 7 returns request with [" "]

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, web

In laravel View I'm trying to return from mysql db some data.I'm using this code:

```
{{$user->cars()->get()->pluck('name')}}
```

and I get

```
["BMW"] ["Opel"] ["Nissan"]
```

instead of:

```
 BMW Opel Nissan
```

I tried with toString,but it's not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with collection function implode,

see: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-implode

Try `{{$user->cars()->get()->implode('name', ' ')}}`

Comment: Good answer. would be better with the code relevant to the question 